# How to check if a node exist before another node in an XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, python-3.x, lxml

I want to check if a node in an XML file exist before another node in Python 3.2. I am using the LXML library for Python. I thought of using a counter to keep track of the order, but i couldn't come up with the logic. I need to do this without changing the XML file.

My XML looks like this [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
For example i want to check if book id="bk108" is before book id="bk112"
except the book id is not in order for my XML. Eg: it doesn't go bk108,bk109...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using XPath

```
not(empty(//book[@id="bk108"][following-sibling::book[@id="bk112"]]))
```

This XPath returns true if there is a `book` node with the id *bk108* which does have a following `book` node with the id *bk112*

Comment: I want to check to see if the bk108 is before the bk112 and not the other way around. I know how to find the element

Comment: @Rohit My code does exactly that. It returns `true` iff bk108 is before bk112. If bk108 has a following node bk112 it follows that bk108 has a position lower than bk112.